# Is there a documented way to get all the state stores of Kafka Stream?

Tags: state, store, apache-kafka-streams, topology

The documentation here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#discovering-and-accessing-application-instances-and-their-local-state-stores explains how to query a state store if you know the name of the store. I am unable to find any examples where you can query all the state stores. The following code fragment seems to be able to do it:

```
TopologyDescription tdesc = topology.describe();
for (TopologyDescription.Subtopology sub : tdesc.subtopologies()) {
    for (TopologyDescription.Node node : sub.nodes()) {
        if (node instanceof org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.InternalTopologyBuilder.Processor) {
            InternalTopologyBuilder.Processor proc = (InternalTopologyBuilder.Processor) node;
                System.out.println(proc.stores());
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work. Is there a better way ? Is this future proof ?

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but I had a similar issue...

I use reflection to get it from the Topology:

```
    private Set<String> GetStoresFromTopology(Topology t) {
    var tClass = t.getClass();
    try {
        var field = tClass.getDeclaredField("internalTopologyBuilder");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(t);
        return ((InternalTopologyBuilder) value).allStateStoreNames();
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

I would also prefer a 'safer' way of doing things, but that's the field that Streams uses to check for tables